# Why can't I do this with implicit types in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-typing, c#-3.0

```
var x = new { a = "foobar", b = 42 };
List<x.GetType()> y;
```

Is there a different way to do what I want to do here?

If there's not, I don't really see all that much point in implicit types...

Comment: You can do it, but it takes reflection. I can't remember the exact code off the top of my head, but I'm sure someone will post something soon.

Comment: If you need to know the type of an object, why would you create it anonymously? You use them when type doesn't matter or need to be known.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x.GetType()` is a method call, evaluated at execution time. It therefore can't be used for a *compile-time* concept like the type of a variable. I agree that occasionally it would be quite handy to be able to do something similar (specifying the compile-time type of a variable as a type argument elsewhere), but currently you can't. I can't say I regularly miss it though.

However, you *can* do:

```
var x = new { a = "foobar", b = 42 };
var y = new[] { x };
var z = y.ToList();
```

You could also write a simple extension method to create a list generically:

```
public static List<T> InList<T>(this T item)
{
    return new List<T> { item };
}
```

(Pick a different name if you want :)

Then:

```
var x = new { a = "foobar", b = 42 };
var y = x.InList();
```

As Marc shows, it doesn't actually have to be an extension method at all. The only important thing is that the compiler can use type inference to work out the type parameter for the method so that you don't have to try to name the anonymous type.

Implicitly typed local variables are useful for a variety of reasons, but they're particularly useful in LINQ so that you can create an ad-hoc projection without creating a whole new type explicitly.

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks for the explanation, and the InList() code snippet was what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

There are ways of doing this with a generic method:

```
public static List<T> CreateList<T>(T example) {
    return new List<T>();
}
...
var list = CreateList(x);
```

or by creating a list *with* data and then emptying it...